# tier 2 intra company transfer visa still valid

Tags: visas

we as a family have a tier 2 ICT VISA valid till 28/09/2018 , but w left the uk on the 29/01/2018 was planning to back to uk for a doctor appointment on the 12/6/2018 , do u think there would be a problem with the residency permit as we were out of the country for the past 4 months?

Answer (score 3):

It is going to be a problem. If you're no longer employed at your company's UK site then the basis for the visa no longer exists and so it is invalid even though it is not expired.

You should not have too much trouble getting a visit visa to attend a private medical appointment. Do be aware that you are no longer allowed to use the NHS because you're not a UK resident any more.

Comment: but how would they know if the contract ends or not

Comment: @LamiaElhateem you mean besides you telling the truth when questioned by the border officer?

Comment: of course i will tell the truth its just they never asked me going in the uk , they just check the validity of my residency permit

Comment: @  user16259 and my appointment is with a  private dr not an NHS ONE

Comment: @Lamia Elhateem They’ll know because your sponsor has to report change of circumstances https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/694807/Tier_2_5_sponsor_guidance_04-2018_final_v1.0.pdf#page64